# How to get Jquery data to google pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use my data for google Pie chart but its not working.

When I am using this code

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ['ProductCategory', 'ItemsSold'],
        [dit[0].CategoryName, dit[0].ItemsSold],
        [dit[1].CategoryName, dit[1].ItemsSold],            
        [dit[2].CategoryName, dit[2].ItemsSold]
    ]);
```

It works as I am putting things statically, but when I am using my data in the loop and bind this way then no data appears in the chart

```
   var data1=[];
     var Header= ['ProductCategory', 'ItemsSold'];
     data1.push(Header);
    for (var i = 0; i < dit.length; i++) {
        var temp = [];
         temp.push(dit[i].CategoryName);
         temp.push(parseInt(dit[i].ItemsSold));
         data1.push(temp);


    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([data1]);
```

Here, dit is my dictionary with CategoryName and ItemsSold.

One thing which I noticed is that when I am trying to check "data" in console, the header for former one had 2 types string and int but for the latter, the header contained my whole pairs of data as well.

[Like this for when I used loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cJTO.png)

[Like this for when I use the 1st way and it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Udo.png)

Comment: What's this got to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're starting with an array, here...

```
var data1=[];
```

you do not need to surround with another array, here...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([data1]);
```

change to...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data1);
```